# Writing a function to compute a quantity in python based on a math problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function to compute the quantity

F(n) = n^2 Σ i=1 (i^3)

Read the problem as n squared over Sigma, with i = 1 under the sigma and I cubed at the end of the function.

I am not sure how to approach this idea. I tried setting up a function but I do not know how to use a function in Python to compute the problem we were given.

As mentioned above, I am sorry, but I do not know how to approach this problem.

I suppose the expected output here would be some quantity but because I haven't been able to make much progress, I have no clue what to expect exactly. To give more background, I understand how functions work but do not know how to approach this type of problem. Any help/guidance in writing this code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you post your attempts as code snippets?

Comment: As a starting point this shows how to generate a function to [sum the cube of the first n natural numbers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-program-for-cube-sum-of-first-n-natural-numbers/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

- Use the built-in functions, [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)
- [image]

```py
def my_sigma(n_start: int, n_end: int) -> int:
    return sum([i**3 for i in range(n_start, (n_end**2) + 1)])

# usage
print(my_sigma(1, 3))
>>> 2025
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Math library to take the powers, and use a for loop for the sigma.

I think this would give you an idea,

```
for i in range (a , int(math.pow(n, 2))):
    list_1.append(int(math.pow(i, 3)))
```

You can just put this inside a function with two variables a and n a representing the i in the sigma and n representing the n in the sigma.

You can use the sum function for summing up all the elements in the list if that is what you want.